# Cassandra bulk load dsbulk - Timestamp format issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to load a csv file into cassandra using the dsbulk utility.
I am getting timestamp format issue.

```
Source  : dance,204b0700-7214-3809-9da1-fe5499113b20,1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000,Roman Holiday,,,\u000a
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse '1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000'; accepted formats are: temporal string (e.g. '2018-09-20T07:52:19.921Z') or numeric value (milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)

Suppressed: java.text.ParseException: Invalid number format: 1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000
Suppressed: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
```

The input file is of this format:

```
cat videos_by_tag.csv.mini2
customs house,d4acc6b9-f9b8-708e-5f7e-9df19a24bf5a,2001-07-12 10:00:00+0000,The Score,,,
dance,204b0700-7214-3809-9da1-fe5499113b20,1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000,Roman Holiday,,,
dance,262ebef4-0626-4758-d0cd-4b72ad1526a7,2000-09-21 10:00:00+0000,Dancer in the Dark ,,,
dance,3eea5ebb-6be2-9bdc-68e2-cabf89070855,2015-02-16 08:00:00+0000,Blue,,,
family estate,5b2eb210-b092-3f9c-de29-ea388b5964ae,1993-10-18 10:00:00+0000,The House of the Spirits ,,,
```

I tried overriding the timestamp format option. Did not help.

```
codec.timestamp = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS+NNNN"
```

Versions

- DSE version: 6.0.0
- DataStax Bulk Loade: v1.0.1
- Cassandra: 4.0.0.2284

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE killrvideo.videos_by_tag ( tag text, videoid uuid, added_date timestamp, name text, preview_image_location text, tagged_date timestamp, userid uuid, PRIMARY KEY (tag, videoid) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (videoid ASC)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Could you share dsbulk version, cassandra version and table structure?

Comment: Actually dse version instead of cassandra.

Comment: dse -v : 6.0.0; DataStax Bulk Loader v1.0.1; Cassandra 4.0.0.2284 ; 
CREATE TABLE killrvideo.videos_by_tag (
    tag text,
    videoid uuid,
    added_date timestamp,
    name text,
    preview_image_location text,
    tagged_date timestamp,
    userid uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag, videoid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (videoid ASC)


Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using dsbulk 1.2.0? Using 1.2.0 the import was successful. When using 1.0.1 I got the same error. I did some research on [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/1.1.0/dsbulk/reference/codecOptions.html) and it seems that only a few patterns are supported. So one thing you could do, if using another [dsbulk version](http://downloads.datastax.com/dsbulk/) is not possible, is to change you timestamp format - instead of 1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000 you should have 1953-08-26T10:00:00+00

Comment: Thanks a lot Horia. Using the new version solved this problem. Can you please post it is a answer. 

Also, ran into one more issue. If the column is defined as set<text> , copy command is successfully loads "{'bible', 'moses', 'ramses'}" & "{'televison'}" .
But, dsbulk fails when there are multiple values with com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Could not parse as Json.
Have you faced this issue?

Comment: I'm glad I could help :). Regarding the other issue, no, I haven't ran into it. Maybe you could post another question and specify the complete scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using dsbulk 1.2.0? Using 1.2.0 the import was successful.

When using 1.0.1 I got the same error.

I did some research on [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/1.1.0/dsbulk/reference/codecOptions.html) and it seems that only a few timestamps patterns are supported.

So there would be two possible solutions:

- use [dsbulk 1.2.0 version](http://downloads.datastax.com/dsbulk/)
- reformat  your csv file and change timestamp format; for instance, instead of 1953-08-26 10:00:00+0000 you should have 1953-08-26T10:00:00+00.